# group by and create a transformed json output

Tags: json, group-by, jq

i have data which look like the following
and i need to transform them.

```
[{"us":{"$event":"5bbf4a4f43d8950b5b0cc6d2"},"org":"TΙ UIH","rc":{"$event":"13"}},
{"us":{"$event":"5bbf4a4f43d8950b5b0cc6d3"},"org":"TΙ UIH","rc":{"$event":"13"}},
{"us":{"$event":"5bbf4a4f43d8950b5b0cc6d4"},"org":"AB KIO","rc":{"$event":"13"}},
{"us":{"$event":"5bbf4a4f43d8950b5b0cc6d5"},"org":"GH SVS","rc":{"$event":"17"}}]
```

what i use:

```
`[group_by(.org, .rc."$event")[] | [.[0].rc."$event", .[0].org, length]] |` sort_by(.[0])[]
```

output i get:

```
[
  "13",
  "AB KIO",
  1
]
[
  "17",
  "GH SVS",
  1
]
[
  "13",
  "TΙ UIH",
  2
]
```

How could i get the following format as output?

```
key1: ["",""]
key2: ["",""]
```

where each key us the number of the event, and in the array, we have the unique values of each event's org.

output 
13: ["AB KIO","TΙ UIH"]
17: ["GH SVS"]

Comment: Are you aware that the input and output you've shown are invalid JSON?  Please fix and/or clarify what you intend. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def aggregate_by(f; g):
  reduce .[] as $x  ({}; .[$x|f] += [$x|g]);

map( {rc: (.rc|.["$event"]), org} )
| aggregate_by(.rc; .org)
| map_values(unique)
```

With your sample input modified to make it a JSON array, the above jq program produces:

```
{"13":["AB KIO","TΙ UIH"],"17":["GH SVS"]}
```

Of course many variations are possible, but there is something to be said for postponing the uniquification.